# how to return server response from axios

Tags: async-await, axios

I've looked at some of the other posts on this and it seems I need to apply 'await'  I'm just not sure how to modify the following to do that

```
function sendData(url,emailPass){

    let bodyFormData = new FormData()
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(emailPass)) {
        console.log(key,value)
        bodyFormData.append(key,value)
    }

        
    axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: bodyFormData,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
    })
        .then(function (response){
            return response.data

        })
        .catch(function(response){
            return response
        })

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify the function to return the promise from axios, which returns the response data.

```js
function sendData(url,emailPass){

    let bodyFormData = new FormData()
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(emailPass)) {
        console.log(key,value)
        bodyFormData.append(key,value)
    }

        
    return axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: bodyFormData,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
    })
        .then(function (response){
            return response.data

        })
        .catch(function(response){
            return response
        })

}
```

If you want to use async/await you can do

```js
async function sendData(url,emailPass){

    let bodyFormData = new FormData()
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(emailPass)) {
        console.log(key,value)
        bodyFormData.append(key,value)
    }
    
    try{
        const response = await axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: bodyFormData,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
        });
        return response.data;
    }catch(e){
        return e.response.data;   
    }
}
```

Comment: your first method doesn't really work.  When I try it I get the following: Promise {<pending>}
axios.js:20 <pre>{"formEmail":"abc@gmail.com","formPassword":"compas"}</pre><pre>Array
(
)
</pre><pre>[{"user":"NOT FOUND"}]</pre>  the promise is what coming back from the return statement the actual response.data is coming from a console.log() just before the return.  I want to return a js object

Comment: your second method doesn't work either as it destroys my catch block

Comment: The first one depends on how you are calling that function. If you don't .then() it that will happen. I've edited the second to demonstrate how to use a try/catch block.